# How to change a form's containing div after validation & submission?

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form that validates using jquery.  The form's id is "contact" and it's inside of a div called "formdiv".

I want it to, on submit, instead of taking me to a new page "contact_received.php", replace the contents of "formdiv" with the contents of "contact_received.php" including the submitted $_GET data.  (e.g.: echo 'thank you, '.$_GET['name'].' for contacting us, we'll get back to you about '.$_GET['message']).  I looked for something similar online & figured I would use jquery submit handler:

```
$("#contact").validate({    
rules: {SOME RULES-clipped for length}, 
messages: {SOME MESSAGES-clipped for length},

submitHandler: function() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: '/contact_received.php',
        type: "GET",
        data: datastring,    
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {             
            $('#formdiv').fadeOut('slow',complete);
            function complete() { 
                $('#formdiv').fadeIn('slow').html(html); 
                $('.loading').hide();
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

form code is here:

```
<div id="formdiv">

    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="/contact_received.php" method="get">

        Your Name

        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" style="display:block;">

     Your Email

      <input type="text" name="email" value="" style="display:block;">

      messsage

      <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="5" style="display:block;"></textarea>

     <input type="submit" class="btn" value=

      "Contact Us" name="Submit">

  </form> 
</div>
```

This doesn't break the validation, but it just takes me right through to the contact_received.php page.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: to be clear, the validation is working fine everything is good except I don't want it to submit.  SHould I remove the "action" from the form?

Comment: Yes, give that a try. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code on my PC and it works well. I have even added some rules and messages.

```
$("#contact").validate({
    rules : {
        name : { required: true, minlength: 3 },
        email : { required: true, email: true },
        message: { required: true, minlength: 5 }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
           required: "We need your name to identify you",
           minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
        },
        email: {
           required: "We need your email address to contact you",
           email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com",
        },
        message: {
            required: "You need to write something",
            minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required!")
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: './contact_received.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: 'name=Romain&message=something',    
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {            
                $('#formdiv').fadeOut('slow',complete);
                function complete() { 
                    $('#formdiv').fadeIn('slow').html(html); 
                    $('.loading').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I suggest you show us your rules and messages. If you have a syntax error in the javascript code, then you are redirected on the targeted page.

(Tip : to see Javascript errors in Firefox, go to the main Firefox menu => Web development => Errors console). I hope the menus are the same in English, I'm French.

**EDIT : I also have added a period before your php file's name : `url: './contact_received.php'`. On my computer if I don't write it, nothing happens when I submit the form (no redirection, nothing)**

Comment: Thank you, what I had done was I'd never populated "datastring" as $("#contact").serialize(); so datastring was empty and it never submitted.  I thought datastring was just an Ajax way to say "the POST data" When you hard coded it out it made me realize my mistake.

Comment: Pleased this has helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are using the validate plugin. Try changing this:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="/contact_received.php" method="get">
```

to this:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="">
```

And remove the return false that I offered up earlier when I didn't have the form code.

OK, now that we are past that. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/contact_received.php',
    type: "GET",
    data: datastring,    
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        function complete() { 
            $('#formdiv').fadeIn('slow').html(html); 
            $('.loading').hide();
        }             
        $('#formdiv').fadeOut('slow',complete);

    }
});
```

I adjusted the ajax function to define the complete function before it's called rather than after like you had it.

Give that a try.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't change anything.  It's inside the validation, I'll edit it to include the whole jquery script.

Comment: Well, I could keep guessing but without the form code, it's hard to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Oh I'll include that too, sorry.

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  When I do this, on submit I get returned to the initial page (with $_GET data appended in url) the problem is that the containing DIV hasn't been swapped out.

Comment: Updated my answer by adjusting the ajax. Take a look and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I changed the ajax but it didn't change anything. It just reloads the page the form is on with $_GET appended to url. I suppose I could workaround by saying in the php form the form "if($_GET['email']) {load thank you page;}else{ show form;}" but I'd really like it to submit and swap via ajax.